# What determines when a file is added to projectile-recentf?

Tags: projectile, recentf

I'm not really sure how it's supposed to work, but when I use helm-projectile-recentf, I don't find the most recent files. Sometimes I do and sometimes I don't;)

I always find them with helm-recentf, though.

What are the criteria for files to be added to projectile-recentf?

Of course, the files are part of the same projectile, even the same directory, but if I visit a file, then switch to another file in the same directory, then try projectile-recentf again, the file is not there;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like projectile uses the `recentf-list` and filters those to the list that starts with `project-root`. See `projectile-recentf-files`.  The only thing I can think of to describe what you see is that the project-root defined in projectile isn't the same as what the filenames expand to, so it appears they do not show up.

Comment: projectile-project-root is nil, so where does it take the root from? I have .git in root, so I guess it picks it up from there, but what variable does projectile-recentf-files use?

Comment: it uses the function `(projectile-acquire-root)`. That in turn calls `projectile-project-root`. that function is more complicated and it looks like it is eventually looking in projectile-project-root-cache.